# Finding winner and second winner

Tags: algorithm, tree, time-complexity, binary-tree, heap

I was going through [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tournament-tree-and-binary-heap/) post about the complexity of finding winner and second winner in least comparisons.

The post says that it will take `n + log(n) - 2` comparisons to do so. I understand that it will take `n-1` comparisons to build heap and to get the winner. But beyond that, I'm not able to understand that how additional `log(n) - 1` comparisons are required to find out the second winner.

As far as I can understand, a constant number of comparisons are further required to find out the second winner because we just need to find the two most recent players who competed with the winner, from the constructed heap and that doesn't add up to `log n - 1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A balanced, single-elimination tournament with `n` participants has `k = ceil(log2(n))` rounds: half of the participants are eliminated in each round; only the final two will play all `k` rounds.

The reason that, in this example, you need compare only the last two opponents of the winner is that there are only 2 rounds shown.  In the "real world", *any* of the teams eliminate by the eventual champion could be the second-best (under the given assumption that superiority is invariant between any two players and transitive among all players).

Thus, you must compare the `k` players that lost to the champion.  Since each comparison eliminates one player, you need `k-1` comparisons to find the single remaining candidate for the silver medal.